# How to teach Ubuntu 15.04 Russian spelling system the ё letter?

Tags: 15.04, internationalization, spell-checking, russian

I have just installed a clean Ubuntu 15.04 system and was very disappointed it highlights all the words including the `ё` (yo) letter as wrong and suggests replacing `мёд` (myod: honey) with `мед` (medical), etc.

This happens in both Firefox and LibreOffice and some other programs. What is the best way to fix this? I believe I could play with dictionary settings in the particular apps themselves, but I'd prefer a tidy system-wide solution if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install dictionaries with these letters. Install it this way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:andrew-crew-kuznetsov/xneur-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hunspell-ru-ie-yo
```

If you read Russian, you can get additional information [HERE](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=218003.0)

Comment: Thanks. But this version seems to tolerate replacing ё with е anyway. Isn't there a version opposite to the original - that would suggest correcting е to ё where applicable? I could ask on that forum of course but I just prefer the StackOverflow format  a lot and hate registering on all the forums :-]

Comment: That used to be the case some years ago in Ubuntu. But then they changed it to the opposite. Your requirement is uncommon. But it is possible to find those old dictionaries somewhere.

Comment: Thank you, @pilot6 . My inner ё-nazi accepts the compromise :-)

Comment: @Pilot6: is it known who permitted a «ё»-discriminating  dictionary to become Ubuntu’s default Russian dictionary?